# Can't import external packages with python

Tags: python

Title. It just doesn't recognize it. For example, I'm trying to make a discord bot with discord.py. I do the pip install thingy, and it just spits this out when I try to run my file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Pixel\Desktop\Discord bot\bot.py". line 1, in <module>
        import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

It does exist, I checked: (C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord) 
Am I doing something wrong here or am I just stupid? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a venv active?

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: close and reopen your editor

Comment: i'm pretty sure I tried that, but i'll try it again

Comment: may be you have more than one python environment.

Comment: Run ```pip freeze```  and check if there is discord available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible reasons for this error. You might have multiple versions of Python running on your machine, so you could have installed the module in a version of Python that your code is not using.

Make sure you're using the write version of Python as your interpreter.

You could also try installing the module directly in whatever venv you're using by typing this command into the terminal in the same folder `python3.9 -m pip install discord`. Replace `python3.9` with whatever version of Python you're using.